# Does two witness addresses with same witnessProgram but with different witness version has the same owner

Tags: bip350-bech32m

With BIP 350 a new version of witness is introduced.

Take these two address from the mainnet:

bc1pmfr3p9j00pfxjh0zmgp99y8zftmd3s5pmedqhyptwy6lm87hf5sspknck9 and bc1qmfr3p9j00pfxjh0zmgp99y8zftmd3s5pmedqhyptwy6lm87hf5sstpn3we.

These two addresses has the same witness program. Does this mean they have the same owner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

In general, this isn't the case. It could that this holds true for hypothetical witness versions that could be introduced in the future.
However, it is not true specifically for P2WSH (the `bc1q` address you posted) and P2TR (the `bc1p` address you posted). In fact, if you ever see two such address, it is almost certainly the case that one is unspendable.

- P2WSH programs encode a SHA256 hash of a script.
- P2TR programs encode the X coordinate of a (possibly, and likely) tweaked public key.

It is unfathomably unlikely that someone could find a public key they have the private key for, whose X coordinates match the hash of a script they know and can spend.